# Ajax loop and history.js for SEO

Tags: loop, seo

For a project, I have to *ajaxify* the main loop with a "load more" button to show more posts (basically as well as [Canva Design School](https://designschool.canva.com/)).
To make this work I used the method described in the [tuts+ getting loopy article](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress--wp-23232).

I had to make a few customization to replace this:

```
$window.scroll(function() {
    var content_offset = $content.offset();
    console.log(content_offset.top);
    if(!loading && ($window.scrollTop() +
        $window.height()) > ($content.scrollTop() +
        $content.height() + content_offset.top)) {
            loading = true;
            page++;
            load_posts();
    }
});
```

with this:

```
$(".load_more").on("click", ".btn", function() {
    $(".load_more").remove();
    if(!loading) {
        loading = true;
        page++;
        load_posts();
    }
});
```

And now it reaches the goal.
The fact is that it is totally SEO un-friendly: there's no native pagination with rel (prev/next) declaration, no basic links to next page either and no chances to get a properly paged URL.

Is there a way to combine this method with history.js? I mean, is it possibile to generate URLs for each page every time the read more button is clicked or it would be better to achieve it in a different way?

Comment: That is what sitemaps are for. Anyway this is an SEO question and not a wordpress one so might be better asked at some other stack (webmasters ?)

Comment: Actually I'm not so sure about this. It is strictly related to WP and its pagination.

Comment: how is it a wordpress specific question which doesn't apply also to jomla and drupal or any other CMS?

Comment: Basically because the method I used to add the ajax function is wordpress based (see the quoted article in the question) and the pagination (avoided) is a wordpress pagination. I'm asking about that. 
 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some plugins that add the next/prev links in `<head>` and follow [Google recomendations for paginated archives](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html), which are similar to [recomendations for infinite scroll](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly.html). If you are interested in doing it at yor own, you can implement the ajax load-more in archive templates and do something like this (not fully tested, just an example):

```
// Print next and prev links for paged categories/archive/tags..etc
add_action( 'wp_head', 'cyb_next_prev_links_for_archives' );
function cyb_next_prev_links_for_archives() {

    if ( ! is_singular() ) {

        //No singular. We are in archive based pages

        global $paged;

        if( get_previous_posts_link() ){
            echo "<link rel='prev' href='" .get_pagenum_link( $paged - 1 ). "'>\n";
        }

        if( get_next_posts_link() ){
            echo "<link rel='next' href='" .get_pagenum_link( $paged + 1 ). "'>\n";
        }


    }

}
```

Also, it is worth to mention that [rel="next" and rel="prev" links for archives have been proposed and approved for future releases](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18672).

Comment: This is very useful. Just one thing I still don't understand: using ajax for pagination the URL doesn't change (unless we don't use something like history.js). With the method you described should I care about it? I mean, do I still have to change also the URL on click event or Google will be fine just with the rel links? Does the same logic apply to the front-page as well? (ok, maybe it is more than "just one thing", sorry)

Comment: As explained in the linked posts from Google Webmaster Central Blog, the `rel="next"` and `rel="prev"` links in the the `<head>` of the document is all that Google needs to properly crawl the paginated archives of your site. Please, read those references.

Comment: Oh, no, wait, maybe I cannot explain it properly. I've already read the articles, both of them. The fact is that it seems that you need to provide the exact URL as well as the rel links. In the infinite scroll article, at point 2, it says that a URL structure is needed. And, in the first article it says "_rel='prev' and rel='next' act as hints to Google, not absolute directives_". That's why I am pretty puzzled about this, everyone can give his/her own interpretation within these criteria.

Comment: Your question has became totally off-topic here, now it is about Google, not WP. Anyway, you are providing a URL structure using `rel="next"` and `rel="prev"`; when that links are used in `<head>` (quoting): "Pagination values in the <body> will be ignored for Google indexing purposes". About acting as a hint, I think they explain why in the last point of [this post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html): if the links are implemented incorrectly Google won't respect them. Anyway, you still have the sitemap of your site, don't forget it.

Comment: Finally, if you want a more SEO expert view, I recommend to ask in [Webmasters StackExchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies. So, to summarize, rel links in <head> make almost everything but you still have to implement pushState for a better user experience (point #4). This answer the question regarding the lack of SEO-friendly pagination within Canva Design School example and the "getting loopy" tutorial. Now, anyone about the question regarding implementing, in a proper way, the pushState on each load more button click?

Comment: Implementing rel="next" and rel="prev" within WordPress answers the question you made in this thread and solve the SEO problems of ajax pagination in archives following Google recomendations. Please, if you have new quetions, open a new thread. For questions about pushState I recommend to use [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). For SEO implications I recommend [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok, I will do this way. But, actually, just to clarify, the main question was: "_Is there a way to combine this method with history.js? I mean, is it possibile to generate URLs for each page every time the read more button is clicked or it would be better to achieve it in a different way?_" Thanks a ton for everything.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to solve your SEO problem in the correct way, which is using rel="prev" and rel="next" links. Please, note that history.js doesn't fix the SEO problem of infinite scroll. Additionally, that question would be, as Mark Kaplun said, off-topic, as "your method" (pure jQuery) and history.js has nothing to do with WordPress; again, for js/jQuery questinos I recommend [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). If you want to fix the SEO problem of infinite scroll within WordPress, take my answer (if you want, of course).

Comment: Hey, I am sorry, I totally forgot to flag your answer (going to do it now). It works perfectly for WordPress SEO pagination. I've just asked a very similar thing on StackOverflow. Hopefully I will solve this in a short time.